# Update singleton object (unity) in one ViewModel, have binding in other ViewModel update

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, unity-container, prism

I'm using PRISM with a Unity container.

Say I have 3 modules, Module A, Module B, and UserModule. UserModule keeps track of the current user and their privileges, Module A has a View/VM that contains a ComboBox containing all the available users, and Module B has a View/VM that simply displays the current selected user's name.

UserModule registers a singleton instance of UserService which manages the users and provides methods to change the current user.

UserModule.cs

```
    /// Create and register instance of laser service
    this.container.RegisterType<IUserService,UserService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Module A - HeaderViewModel.cs

```
public class HeaderViewModel : BindableBase
   {

       private readonly IUserService _userService;
       private List<IUser> users;
       private IUser curUser;

       public HeaderViewModel(IUserService userService)
       {
           _userService = userService;
           users = _userService.GetUsers();
           curUser = _userService.CurUser;
       }

       public List<IUser> Users
       {
           get { return users; }
       }

       public IUser CurUser
       {
           get { return curUser; }
           set
           {
               SetProperty<IUser>(ref curUser, value);
               _userService.CurUser=curUser;
           }
       }

   }
```

Module A - HeaderView.xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurUser.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Users: "></TextBlock>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurUser, Mode=TwoWay}" ></ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

All of the above works fine, `HeaderView.xaml` loads up with the ComboBox populated, and when I change the user it updates the TextBlock displaying the current User's name, as well as updates the current user object in the UserService singleton.

Now, if I have another `View/VM` from Module B that shows the current user name, it should update automatically as well. But, I haven't been able to successfully get this binding to work.

I can post more code if needed, but my real question is if this approach is possible? If each user has certain privileges, and certain controls base their IsEnabled property based on these privileges, it would be awesome to simply update the current user in the singleton UserService object and through simple binding, all the other `views/vms` across different models automatically update as well. Is this possible? Or do I need to add some kind of "user changed" event and publish it to all view models who will need to update their UI?

Thanks

**Edit 1**
Since someone passive aggressively didn't seem to comprehend what I'm asking, I will clarify. If 2 separate Views both use the same singleton service to get data from, is it possible when View1 modifies this data, that View2 atomically updates via xaml binding only? For example, Imagine you have 2 separate views that allow you to change the current user via ComboBox. When I change the user on View1, is it POSSIBLE, via proper binding, for View2 to automatically update it's selected user?

Comment: Can I ask why a simple Yes or No question like mine gets downvoted?

Comment: It would be good to see what your binding looks like in the other modules. FYI, `TwoWay` binding on a `TexBlock` is not necessary since you can't change the text from the UI. You may need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your text binding to make sure updates occur. If that doesn't work, then an event may be in order.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to simplify my code for this example and have my updated code posted shortly. I was more just curious is anyone has had a similar scenario. For my testing, I'm trying to set the "IsEnabled" property of a control that is bound to the current user's "IsAdmin" property. So only users with "Admin" access will be able to click this button. One view contains the ComboBox of users, and changing a user in this View I was hoping to change the "IsEnabled" property of the button in a different View. Both Views share the same singleton service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by making your service notify the rest of the application of changes to the data.

One possibility for that is to make the service implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then let each view model use [the property observer](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/) to publish the appropiate notifications for its own properties when it receives a notification from the service.

Depending on the size of the application, you might want to roll out some dedicated [CQRS system](http://getcqrs.com/), but for my desktop apps, the `PropertyObserver` normally does very well and gives understandable and refactoring-friendly code.

Answer (score -1):

Just make the Mode on the Binding be TwoWay.